# Customise way in which Spark is read

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have the following data in a CSV file(actually, my real data is larger but this is a good simplification):

```
ColumnA,ColumnB
1,X
5,G
9,F
```

I am reading it the following way, where `url` is the location of the file:

```
val rawData = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(url)
```

For reading, I am using https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Then, I am applying a map on it:

```
val formattedData = rawData.map(me => me("ColumnA") match {
    //some other code
  })
```

However, when I am referencing the column like this: `me("ColumnA")` I am getting a type mismatch:

```
Type mismatch, expected: Int, actual: String
```

Why is this occurring? Shouldn't every row of `rawData` be a Map?

Answer (score 2):

when you reference a perticular column in datafram's row, you have several methods to do this. 
if you are using apply method then you need to pass the index of column.
or if you want to get a column by name you need to use getAs[T] function of Row.

so you can use :

```
me(0)
```

or

```
me.getAs[T]("ColumnA")
```

hope it will help you.